# unable to convert null value to 0

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm working with databricks and I don't understand why I'm not able to convert null value to 0 in what it seems like a regular integer column.

I've tried these two options:

```
@udf(IntegerType())
def null_to_zero(x):
  """
  Helper function to transform Null values to zeros
  """
  return 0 if x == 'null' else x
```

and later:

```
.withColumn("col_test", null_to_zero(col("col")))
```

and everything is returned as null.

and the second option simply doesn't have any impact `.na.fill(value=0,subset=["col"])`

What do I'm missing here? Is this a specific behavior of null values with databricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nulls are represented as `None`, not as a string `null`.  For your case it's better to use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) function instead, like this (example based on docs):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, lit
cDf = spark.createDataFrame([(None, None), (1, None), (None, 2)], ("a", "b"))
cDf.withColumn("col_test", coalesce(cDf["a"], lit(0.0))).show()
```

will give you desired behavior:

```
+----+----+--------+
|   a|   b|col_test|
+----+----+--------+
|null|null|     0.0|
|   1|null|     1.0|
|null|   2|     0.0|
+----+----+--------+
```

If you need more complex logic, then you can use when/otherwise, with condition on null:

```py
cDf.withColumn("col_test", when(cDf["a"].isNull(), lit(0.0)).otherwise(cDf["a"])).show()
```

Comment: and it seems that when I'm trying to evaluate None if I want to build a helper function it doesn't work too `return 0 if x == None else x` Is there a way to do it like this? Why would coalesce be a better option?

Comment: Coalesce will be better option because Spark built in functions are much faster than UDFs. Especially not pandas UDFs

Comment: See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html

Comment: You can’t compare with none using equality. You should use “is None”